# How to bind number of rows/columns to UniformGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

In my XAML I got  this

```
<UniformGrid x:Name="gameGrid" Columns="{Binding GridColumnSize}"  Rows="{Binding GridRowSize}"/>
```

and I want to bind the values to these in my code so I can change them

```
public int GridColumnSize = 5;
public int GridRowSize = 7;
```

It doesn't work though. When I put there for example 35 buttons it will display 6 * 6 grid, since that's how it acts normally. So how do I bind it? Or is there another way?

Comment: Where are `GridColumnSize` and `GridRowSize` defined? Did you set a proper data context to use them via Binding?

Comment: I have no idea how does this work and it's defined in the MainWindow.xaml.cs

Comment: I also tried this

Binding GridRowSize = new Binding(Convert.ToString(gameGrid.Rows));
 GridRowSize.Source = RowSize;
 gameGrid.SetBinding(gameGrid.Rows, GridRowSize);

I converted the gameGrid.Rows first time because it said that it can't convert int to string.
Now it's okay I think but the last gameGrid.Rows says that it can't convert int to System.Windows.DependencyProperty